# Selfcontained project with custom font in MikTeX without installation

Tags: miktex, folders, installing-fonts

I have a template, designed for pdfLaTeX in mikTeX (TeXLive), which uses a custom font. The files of this font are in the root directory of this project. Is there a way to have these (map, vf, tfm..) files in a separate project directory like /fonts without installing any MikTeX package etc? The project must be selfcontained.

[image: Project folder structure]

Thanks for any help.